# Keep BIG folder sincronized on network

Tags: nfs, network-share, windows-server-2016, git, ansible

I have N Windows 2016 servers with a folder which needs to have binaries up-to-date. This folder (actually) haves ~200GB, but it may grow, twice its size or even more.

My idea was to keep those folders updated with Ansible, so every time I want a new server, Ansible will keep everything ready. (one by one is not an option since I can have from 1 to... 1000-10000 servers)

I though of something git-like, but reading about git and big files/binaries I saw that it isn't the best solution. (Maybe mercurial?)

Another idea was to set up an NFS Server and keep all the Servers connected. Then once I want an update, just download that folder (Note: I **DO NOT** want the folder to keep updated on real time). Con: If it's just one change, it would be overkill, every server would need a lot of time.

Looking here and over internet, I found a lot of information but nearly always related to shared disks for enterprise, or real time folders. So, I would know if someone already tried something like that or knows something, and would like to give an opinion about it.

I really like the feature of downloading only the changes of the repo from control version, but I would not use all the others features, like commits, branches, etc... Maybe there is already something to just download the changes from the server?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Have you consider using `rsync`? This program can sync all you files and transfer only new/changed files.

Also consider [DFSR](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/dfsr/dfsr-overview) which is native Microsoft option

Comment: I'm testing rsync, since I can update everything on demand easier with ansible. Thank you!